# Consuming WSDL that requires authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I know how to consume ASMX file in C#.net

Simple

Right Click on References

Then Add Service Reference

Paste the ASMX service in the address bar

Click Go.

What the vendor sent us is a .wsdl link that needs userid and password.

how can I consume that in my application?

I tried to google that

most of the pages talk about asmx or wsdl without authentication.

will appreciate if someone helped me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming it's [basic authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication):

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "......";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "......";
```

Comment: There is no client in the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication can you show to use username and password based on the link you posted

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication#client